# CakePHP equivalent of html code

Tags: php, html, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a cakePHP project and I need to create a button using PHP that will delete an entry in a database, but I want to display the twitter bootstrap trashcan icon on said button.

The code to include the icon from twitter bootstrap is;

```
<i class="icon-trash"></i>
```

And the PHP code I need it to work in is;

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), 
    array(
        'action' => 'delete', 
        $skill['Skill']['SkillID']),
        array(
              'class'=>'btn'),
              null, 
              __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', 
              $skill['Skill']['SkillID']
));?>
```

Does anyone know how to implement the html in this PHP code so I can replace the text 'Delete' with the icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
    '<i class="icon-trash"></i> '.__('Delete'), 
    array(
        'action' => 'delete', 
        $skill['Skill']['SkillID']
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'btn',
        'escape' => false
    ),
    null, 
    __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', 
        $skill['Skill']['SkillID'] )
);
```

`'escape' => false` makes CakePHP display the HTML unescaped.

It might (depending on the CSS) also work if you just add the `icon-trash` class to the link.

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), 
    array(
        'action' => 'delete', 
        $skill['Skill']['SkillID']),
        array(
              'class'=>'btn icon-trash'),
              null, 
              __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', 
              $skill['Skill']['SkillID']
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're using CakePHP and Twitter Bootstrap, there is a great helper plugin which will make your life easier https://github.com/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper

Then look at the button method. I'm pretty sure you can just pass it an 'icon' => 'iconname' in the parameters array